# What is it called when someone glides through a building's external door behind you?

Tags: social-engineering, physical-access, rfid

One form of social engineering is the practice of running up to a building's external door just as an employee is entering. The employee often holds the door open for the intruder, bypassing security systems (RFID systems, for example).

Is there a name for this specific practice?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but it answers your question. As this is basically an English terminology question and the concept is well-known, I'm making this a duplicate of a question that also references what the term means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tailgating` or `piggybacking`.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggybacking_(security)

Comment: According to that link, piggybacking implies consent by the person being followed, whereas tailgating doesn't. Not sure if it matters, but interesting.